# Cover Image is not showing correctly with Bootstrap/MDBootstrap on mobile devices, Live Server Problem

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, material-design, mdbootstrap

I have an image, .jpg, that I am using as my cover image for this project. It works perfectly on desktop but I can't see anything on it for mobile devices. I don't know if it's zoomed in or not but I can't see an image but instead of a color gradient as the background. Whoever, what's weird is when I used "Live Server" on Vscode, the image is there at any sizes, even on mobile but when I host it on Netlify and look at the site on a physical phone, then it's not showing. Why does this happen on Live Server, because this keeps confusing me into thinking that my site is complete only to realize that it's not showing correctly on mobile devices? The dimension of the image is 5585 x 3141 and here's some of my code for this. Note, I did not want to include everything in the HTML, divs, it's a long list of code for other stuff so assume that the closing tags are there (unless you need the other half of that section).[Mobile background/cover image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAyPV.jpg).
[Desktop background/cover image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XHZN.jpg)

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Spacing so navbar does not cover up the sections */
h2, #darkmode{
    padding-top: 60px;
}
#intro {
    background: url(../img/colorimage.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.top-nav-collapse {
  background-color: #24355C;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background-color: #24355C;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background-color: #24355C;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Main Navigation-->
    <header>
        <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar">

            <div class="container">

                <!-- Navbar brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <!-- Collapse button -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler first-button " type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent20" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent20"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                </button>

                <!-- Collapsible content -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent20">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto smooth-scroll">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#intro">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#best-features">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#examples">Examples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Links -->

                    <!-- Social Icon  -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Collapsible content -->

            </div>

        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <!--Mask-->
        <div id="intro" class="view">

            <div class="mask rgba-black-strong">

                <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">

                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">

                        <div class="col-md-10">

                            <!-- Heading -->
                            <h2 class="display-4 font-weight-bold white-text pt-5 mb-2">Your Name</h2>

                            <!-- Divider -->
                            <hr class="hr-light">

                            <!-- Description -->
                            <h4 class="white-text my-4">Welcome to my first project</h4>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-white" href="#darkmode" role="button">Read more<i
                                    class="fa fa-book ml-2"></i></a>
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-white">Read more<i
                                    class="fa fa-book ml-2"></i></button> -->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Mask-->

    </header>
    <!--Main Navigation-->
```

Comment: Can you please add complete HTML code? Here `top-nav-collapse` not included in your code..!!!

Comment: So I realized that running the code snippet is an option. It will not run correctly. I do not have all the code imported here.

Comment: Or can you add codepen demo or jsfiddle ?

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Spacing so navbar does not cover up the sections */
h2, #darkmode{
    padding-top: 60px;
}
#intro {
    background: url(https://photorator.com/photos/images/kirkjufell-under-the-midnight-sun-iceland-photo-by-coolbiere-a-x-post-rsland-42750.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.top-nav-collapse {
  background-color: #24355C;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background-color: #24355C;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
  .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
    background-color: #24355C;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Main Navigation-->
    <header>
        <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar">

            <div class="container">

                <!-- Navbar brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <!-- Collapse button -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler first-button " type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent20" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent20"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                </button>

                <!-- Collapsible content -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent20">

                    <!-- Links -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto smooth-scroll">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#intro">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#best-features">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#examples">Examples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="middle nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Links -->

                    <!-- Social Icon  -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Collapsible content -->

            </div>

        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <!--Mask-->
        <div id="intro" class="view">

            <div class="mask rgba-black-strong">

                <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">

                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">

                        <div class="col-md-10">

                            <!-- Heading -->
                            <h2 class="display-4 font-weight-bold white-text pt-5 mb-2">Your Name</h2>

                            <!-- Divider -->
                            <hr class="hr-light">

                            <!-- Description -->
                            <h4 class="white-text my-4">Welcome to my first project</h4>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-white" href="#darkmode" role="button">Read more<i
                                    class="fa fa-book ml-2"></i></a>
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-white">Read more<i
                                    class="fa fa-book ml-2"></i></button> -->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Mask-->

    </header>
    <!--Main Navigation-->
```

Comment: I have the scripts, stylesheets, already included all from MDB before posting it here. This doesn't work/solved the problem.

Comment: please add [codepen](https://codepen.io/) demo for more try ?

Comment: I think it has something to do with either the stylesheet or the MDB classes/attributes applied to it.

Comment: Never used it before, code has various sources from all different places with node_modules included.